# Center images without using all width

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I`m making my first theme for Wordpress and got pretty stuck on this.
How can I align this images like this, without getting the a-tag using all the width.(If you click on right side of the first images, you are following the link without clicking on the image).

(link to site deleted)

I don`t want to set a fixed width on the images, but still having them centered without the anchor to take the full width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try styling the text-align of the p's (text-align: center e.g.) and then changing the style on the img tags.

```
img{
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hnmph56u/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the anchor to display block and then give it a width and margin: 0 auto.
than set the img width to 100%.

I prefer this than using display inline because it gives less problems in some layouts.